# Help finding number so I can find the set

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

I am looking for the codes of these 2 bricks. I inherited a big box of LEGO, but can't find the number to identify the set they go in.

[image: windowstrong text][image: triangle part]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  Congratulations, you've got 40+ years old LEGO parts there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's [772p01 - Brick 1 x 2 x 2 without Bottom Tube with Window Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=772p01#T=C) was available in one of these [4 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=772p01&colorID=12&in=A).

[image]

And [3145 - Vehicle, Tipper End Flat with Pins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3145#T=C) in White color could be found in just [2 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3145&colorID=1&in=A).

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! I have found and build the sets